# remove specific classes from menu items

Tags: menus, filters, navigation

I want to remove some specific class names from the menu items
For example I need to remove classes of `fa` and `fa-desktop` from all menu items in WordPress

```
<li id="menu-item-21" class="dropdown-header fa fa-desktop menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-has-children dropdown col-sm-4 menu-col menu-item-21 dropdown">
```

Thank you

Comment: custom walker class? do share walker class here. it will be easy to understand your situation and you can get better help.

Comment: @AbdulRehman can you check my next answer? I used this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'special_nav_class', 10, 2);
function special_nav_class($classes, $item){
    if(($key = array_search('fa', $classes)) !== false) {
        unset($classes[$key]);
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

Comment: This is not a walker, it's a filter. Also, "fa fa-desktop" are not built-in classes, they're being added by something else - perhaps you're using Font Awesome or some kind of plugin that is adding them. Could you please share your code where you actually call wp_nav_menu? Also - it's better to use the "edit" link to adjust your question rather than adding more question details as an answer. :)

Comment: @WebElaine this fixed my problem, forget walker :)